# Windows Media Streaming Live Event

Tags: windows

What would be the best software for me to use to do a windows media live stream.  I have a CDN from softlayer and would like to start using this for live streaming.  I own Expression Encoder but other people that I want to have use it do not.

I need the software to be able to send what I see on my computer screen with sound.

Comment: This is very vague, pretty much impossible to answer as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you want is [Windows Media Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448620.aspx).  This consists of at least 1 2008 r2 server with the media serives role installed, and at least 1 client running an encoder (like expression encoder).  You can certainly use the CDN for caching the live content if it is compatible with media services (a quick peek at the softlayer site didn't show anything about WMS so I'm not sure that it will be).  As an example of one that is compatible see [internap](http://www.internap.com/cdn-services-content-delivery-network/)

Comment: Is there anything better than expression encoder or windows media encoder.  I was looking for something that did titles and such.  If it dosent existing then so be it

Comment: I have marked this as the answer.  I just noticed that the free version of expression encoder supports Live Encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - ok, CDN is USELESS. Seriously. LIVE STREAMING means LIVE, no content to deliver to a CDN first. What you need is a server running media services. Plus media encoder on the capture computer, delivering the stream to the media services computer where clients pick it up. RTFM for media services.

Start at

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-at/library/bb629405(en-us).aspx

Comment: I already have media encoder.  I am just looking for something similar in functionality to www.livestreaming.com for microsoft

Comment: Are you using a server OS or client OS? Also what version?

Comment: Both. Server os on the server, client os on the client, and i dont like outdated software, so i use the current version.